# Geoserver auto startup error. Status active: Active (exited)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, geoserver

I have problem trying to auto startup geoserver. When I open as manual it opens the web, but when I try to auto startup it cannot open the web. I already follow the instruction in

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/linuxscript.html.

But I get the error below

[image]

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: what does the geoserver log file say?